# site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.None) is raising the following error:- "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, event-receivers, farm-solution

i have the following code , where i am trying to create a new user Group inside my RootSite, and do not assign any permission for it (as i am going to use it inside some sub-sites which have unique permissions). so i tried the following:-

```
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.None);
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
site.RootWeb.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
site.RootWeb.Update();
```

but i got this exception:-

> "Value does not fall within the expected range."

on the following line of code:-

```
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.None);
```

So can anyone advice on this please? as when i create a new Group using the UI i can set a group without any permission levels..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to just create a new group, you don't need to use the `SPRoleDefinition` object.

You just need to add the group to the site group like this:

```
site.RootWeb.SiteGroups.Add("GroupName", site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators[0], site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators[0], "Your Group Description");
```

(insted of `site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators[0]` you can use any other user)

Comment: so you mean in this case the group will be added to the RootWeb without any permission is this correct? and later on i can assign this Group to a sub-site (which have unique permission) and assign it a permission level (such as Contribute)???

Comment: can you adivce on my above comment please? and thanks for the useful reply..

Comment: Yes, the group will be added to the RootWeb without any permission, and yes, you can assign later contribute permission on a sub-site

Answer (score 0):

There was bug you cannot get RoleDefinition by Type for None. To workaround it I used this piece of code:

```
    if (roleDefinition.Type != SPRoleType.None)
{
     definition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleDefinition.Type);
     roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(definition);
}
else
{
     definition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetById(roleDefinition.Id);
     roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(definition);
}
```

[Ref:](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/993b34f5-4232-40d2-829c-420f4499a9d6/setting-permissions-using-sproletype?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

Comment: so how i should define the "roleDefinition" ?? something as follow:- "_SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = new SPRoleDefinition();_"

Answer (score 0):

As per the [following blog](http://mosswat.blogspot.com/2009/07/spwebroledefinitionsgetbytypesproletype.html) and [following the post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/993b34f5-4232-40d2-829c-420f4499a9d6/setting-permissions-using-sproletype?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy). they having the issue when SPROLETYPE.NONE and they fix it using this code. RoleDefinition not worked with the type rather it is fine using the RoleDefiniation.ID

```
if (roleDefinition.Type != SPRoleType.None)
{
 definition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleDefinition.Type);
 roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(definition);
}
else
{
 definition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetById(roleDefinition.Id);
 roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(definition);
}
```

Comment: but can you advice how i need to create the roleDefinition? for example as follow :- "_SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = new SPRoleDefinition();_"?

Comment: have you tried this one SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetById(roleDefinition.Id)?

Comment: where i need to place this ? instead of "_SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.None);_"?

Comment: also i am not sure how you want me to reference roleDefinition inside a new roleDefinition !!

Comment: i am not developer but i refer the post which explain it as bug, i just give u an idea how can you create new sprole definition....i copy it from your codeline